# Smallest prime of the form $\frac{a^n + 1}{a+1}$ has $ 1 < n < a + 2$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, upper-lower-bounds, fermat-numbers

Consider primes of the form

$$\frac{a^n + 1}{a+1}$$

for integer $a>1$ and integer $n>1$.

Conjecture :

(for any fixed $a$)

The smallest prime of the form $\frac{a^n + 1}{a+1}$ has $ 1 < n < a^2$.

This true for $a=2$ or small $a$ and it seems to hold even for large $a$.

For instance the primes

$$521 = \frac{5^5 + 1}{6}$$

$$1824841 = \frac{37^5 + 1}{38}$$

$$530713 = \frac{729^3 + 1}{730}$$

Now this might be hard to prove ofcourse considering the open conjectures surrounding these numbers and assuming I did not miss a trivial thing like modular arithmetic.

So my main question is rather : how much can the conjecture be sharpened ?

Can we say

The smallest prime of the form $\frac{a^n + 1}{a+1}$ has $ 1 < n < a + 2$ or

The smallest prime of the form $\frac{a^n + 1}{a+1}$ has $ 1 < n < p(a)$ where $p(a)$ is the $a$ th prime.

or such ?

Let us denote $f(a)$ for the lowest bound.

From the example above I got $f(a) = a$ (the case with $a = 5$) for $a>2$ and $f(2) = 3$

Comment: Personally I think these conjectures are probably not true. As Einar Rødland mentions in their answer, a probabilistic heuristic suggests that the prime values are very sparse on average.

Comment: $$({53^{21943} + 1})/{54}$$ is the smallest prime of the form $$({53^p + 1})/{54}$$ by the way

Comment: @Aurel-BG how did you find that ? Did you keep a list of previous factors to sieve ?

Comment: Sure, I found this here https://www.fermatquotient.com/PrimSerien/GenRepuP.txt or https://oeis.org/A084742

Comment: I just realised that one of the cases listed is an odd power as $a=729=9^3$ which makes a prime for $n=3$. My proof for no odd primes, however, only applies to $a=r^k$ where $n>k$.

Comment: @EinarRødland thanks for the update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran a check for $a$ from $2$ to $100$ and here are some cases of interest. Note that I only checked for $n<1000$ (some extended to $n<2000$). Also, note that $n$ must be odd for $x=(a^n+1)/(a+1)$ to be an integer. It must also be prime, otherwise $x$ will be composite as $a^p+1$ divides $a^n+1$ if $p|n$, and so $(a^p+1)/(a+1)$ is a nontrivial factor.

If $a=r^k$ for some odd $k$, we can factor $a^n+1=(r^n+1)(r^{(k-1)n}-\cdots-r^n+1)$. For $n>k$, both terms of the product are greater than $a+1$, and so $x=(r^{kn}+1)/(r^k+1)$ must be composite, as Aurel-BG and Calvin Lin have both pointed out. However, there may be solutions for $a=r^p$ for which $n=p$ is the only possible solution: see addition at the end.

Apart from the odd powers $a=8,27,32,64$, I found no prime for $a=53,97$, but Aurel-BG found $(53^{21943}+1)/54$ to be the smallest for $a=53$, and my guess is that there will exist one for $a=97$ as well.

In most cases, a prime is found for low $n$, but there are some notable exceptions for which $n>a$: $(a,n)=(30,139)$, $(31,109)$, $(40,53)$, $(45,103)$, $(50,1153)$, $(53,21943)$, $(68,757)$, $(82,293)$, $(87,167)$, $(88,709)$.

The prime density around numbers of size $x$ is $\sim 1/\ln x$, which for $x=(a^n+1)/(a+1)$ is $\sim 1/n\ln a$. Summing this expected prime density over all odd $n$ gives an infinite sum which is an argument in favour of there being infinitely many primes on that form, but also that if none is found for low $n$ the first $n$ may be very high. This is true even if you add the constraint that $n$ be prime.

---

I checked for solutions on the form $a=r^p$ for prime $p$. For $x$ to be prime, the only option is $n=p$. However, there seems to be lots of such cases. The poster already had $a=729=9^3$ included, and from computational test I find a lot and would not be surprised if there are an infinite number of them.

I started a search, the first hit being $a=6^3, n=3$, and the largest found so far being $a=601^{29}, n=29$.

Comment: There are no primes for $8, 27, 32, 64$. It's always composite. For $97$, if it exists, $n$ must be $> 500000$

Comment: For $ a = 8$, we have $ (a^n+1)/(a+1) = (2^{2n} - 2^n + 1) ( 2^n + 1) / 9$. We can further show that both terms are a multiple of 3 iff $2^n + 1 \equiv 0 \pmod{3}$, and since both terms are $> 3$ hence the expression is composite.

Comment: @Einar so what is the estimate for $f(a)$ ? 
Is it $\exp(a)$ ? Or $a^e$ or $a^3$ ?

Comment: @mick, my best guess would be that there will be no strict upper bound on $f(a)$, but that with the exception of odd powers ($a=k^3,k^5,\ldots$) and perhaps some other special cases, all $a$ should have a prime. There may be some statistical properties: eg my suggestion that either $f(a)$ will be low or it may be very high, ie a very long-tailed distribution. The computed cases seem to support that.